# sharing sessions accross browsers and flex air

Tags: java, apache-flex, session, tomcat, blazeds

Is there any way to share a session between a java web app and an AIR app that uses blazeDS?  The goal is some kind of single sign on, so when either one of the apps is logged into that the user would not need to log into the other.  They're both running in the same tomcat, but they are different apps.

Answer (score -1):

use local connection and make them talk to each other and share their status.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: -1 as LocalConnection is for two SWFs to communicate at the client side.